# jQuery Progress Bar Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a jQuery novice and I am trying to build a dynamic jQuery progress bar. What I need to do is offer a series of checkboxes on a page so that when the visitor checks or unchecks a checkbox it will increase or decrease the value shown on the progress bar. In addition, I need to alert the visitor when they have reached the maximum amount (percentage). Any help would be appreciated. The code below will bind the click event to the progressbar but it doesn't increase or decrease correctly and my max doesn't appear to work?

Here is what I have:

Javascript:

```
<head>

<link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#budgetbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });
       $(".option1").click(function () {
                     $("#budgetbar").progressbar({ value: 10 });

       });
       $(".option2").click(function () {
                     $("#budgetbar").progressbar({ value: 50 });

       });
           $(".option3").click(function () {
                     $("#budgetbar").progressbar({ value: 20 });

       });
       $(".option4").click(function () {
                     $("#budgetbar").progressbar({ value: 50 });

       });

   $("#budgetbar").progressBar({ max: 100, textFormat: 'fraction', callback: function(data) { if (data.running_value == data.value) { alert("Budget limit reached!"); } }} );

});
</script>

</head>
```

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="budgetbar"></div>  
<div>    
    <input type="checkbox" class="option1" />Expense 1 - $100,000<br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="option2" />Expense 2 - $500,000<br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="option3" />Expense 3 - $200,000<br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="option4" />Expense 4 - $500,000<br />
* Max Expenses - $1,000,000 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value of jQuery UI progress bar by using

```
$("#budgetbar").progressbar("option", "value", 25);
```

This only sets the value to 25 (not increases by 25). To get the value you can use

```
$("#budgetbar").progressbar("option", "value");
```

And you are probably going to need to check if the checkbox is checked :-)

I would do it like this (not tested)

```
var $budgetbar = $("#budgetbar"); // It's no good to repeat selections
$(".option1").click(function () {
    var thisValue = 25, // This checkbox' value
        currentValue = $budgetbar.progressbar("option", "value"),
        newValue;
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        newValue = currentValue + thisValue; // add
    } else {
        newValue = currentValue - thisValue; // subtract
    }
    $budgetbar.progressbar("option", "value", newValue)
});
```

Edit, the alert (there may be a better way):

```
$budgetbar.bind("progressbarchange", function(event, ui) {
    var value = $budgetbar.progressbar("option", "value");
    if (value > 100) {
        alert("You're over 100");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew but I don't understand where that would go in my script? Also will that increase or decrease the value if multiple boxes are checked or unchecked?

Comment: That worked great! I just had to add an initial value to the #budgetbar like this:
    var $budgetbar = $("#budgetbar").progressbar({ value: 0 }); 

Now the only issue I have left is alerting the visitor when they have reached the 100% limit. Every time I add this line to the script it says "$budgetbar.progressBar is not a function":


    $budgetbar.progressBar({ max: 100, textFormat: 'fraction',     callback: function(data) { if (data.running_value == data.value) { alert("Budget limit reached!"); } }} );

Any thoughts on this line?

Comment: I just posted a solution above that has the alert working correctly, maybe you can use that.

Comment: @JonathanPayne

I keep getting an error that says $budgetbar.progressbar is not a function? Here Is my code:

    $( "#budgetbar" ).progressbar( "option" , "value" , newValue )

        if ( newValue > 100 )
        {
            alert( "You have exceeded the maximum value of 100" );
        }

Comment: I've added code for handling the alert to the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code quite a bit if you assign values to your `input` checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="option" value="10"/> Expense 1 - $100,000<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="option" value="50"/> Expense 2 - $500,000<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="option" value="20"/> Expense 3 - $200,000<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="option" value="50"/> Expense 4 - $500,000<br />
```

This way, you don't have to handle each checkbox differently.  Instead you can use a ***single*** handler for all of your options.  This makes debug and code maintenance *a lot* simpler.

Secondly, as each option changes, you want to assign the *total* value to the `progressbar`, not just the clicked option's value.  Use `change` instead of `click`, as this will only fire when a checkbox changes its state.  (Minor difference, I know).

```
// The only handler you need:
$('.option').on('change', function() {
    // The total
    var total = 0;

    // Sum the value of all checked checkboxes
    $('.option:checked').each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    // Assign the value using the correct method:
    $("#budgetbar").progressbar("value", total );
});
```

Also, you are using `progressBar` on your call to set the parameters (note the capital B).  The correct name is `progressbar`.

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/DjWCz/2/

**HTML:** (note the class name change and value addition)

```
<input type="checkbox" class="option" value="10"/> Expense 1 - $100,000<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="option" value="50"/> Expense 2 - $500,000<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="option" value="20"/> Expense 3 - $200,000<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="option" value="50"/> Expense 4 - $500,000<br />
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#budgetbar").progressbar({
        value: 0,
        max: 100,
        textFormat: 'fraction',
        complete: function(event, ui) {
            alert("Budget limit reached!");
        }
    });

    $('.option').on('change', function() {
        var total = 0;

        $('.option:checked').each(function() {
            total += parseInt($(this).val());
        });

        $("#budgetbar").progressbar("value", total );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: When I tried your code the progress bar disappeared. So I added the one line below, but it still wouldn't increase/decrease the value.

    
         $("#budgetbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });

Comment: You still need the initialization code.  See edit above.  It works in the jsfiddle.  Use that as a reference.

Comment: Also, note that I changed the class names of your options.  They should all have `class="option"`.

Comment: That works great, and the code is much simpler...thank you! One issue I have to resolve is the limit is set to 100. However, the total of all the checkboxes could exceed 100 depending on the boxes you choose. Can I alert the visitor when they reach the limit of 100 and prevent them or alert them when they have exceeded the limit?

Comment: You are already calculating the total in the change handler.  You can put code there to warn/prevent exceeding the budget.  this example warns you when you have reached and exceeded the budget: http://jsfiddle.net/DjWCz/3/

Comment: This version doesn't let you select options that would exceed the budget: http://jsfiddle.net/DjWCz/4/  You could also just disable the options, depending on what you want to do.  Note, there are a number of html and script changes in this version.

Comment: Great, could you accept my answer then?  (Accepting answers will make people more willing to answer your questions in the future)  To accept an answer, click on the check mark under the number next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store the value of the progress bar on a variable, that way you can increase or decrease its value to have the right calculation.

it will be something like:

```
previousValue = 0;
$("#budgetbar").progressbar({ 
    value: 10+previousValue
});
```

Also, you need to check if the checkbox is checked, and not use the "click" event. Try something like this

```
if($('#checkboxId').is(':checked'))
```

Or course, you need to add an id to your checkboxes.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, hope it helps.

Cheers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready( function()
    {
        $( "#budgetbar" ).progressbar();
    });

    var currentProgress = 0;

    function adjustProgress( checkbox )
    {
        if ( $( checkbox ).is( ":checked" ) )
        {
            currentProgress += parseInt( $( checkbox ).val() );
        }
        else
        {
            currentProgress -= parseInt( $( checkbox ).val() );
        }

        $( "#budgetbar" ).progressbar( "option" , "value" , currentProgress )

        if ( currentProgress > 100 )
        {
            alert( "You have exceeded the maximum value of 100" );
        }
    }
</script>

<div id="budgetbar"/>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="option1" value="10" onclick="adjustProgress( this )"/>Expense 1 - $100,000<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="option2" value="50" onclick="adjustProgress( this )"/>Expense 2 - $500,000<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="option3" value="20" onclick="adjustProgress( this )"/>Expense 3 - $200,000<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="option4" value="50" onclick="adjustProgress( this )"/>Expense 4 - $500,000<br/>
    * Max Expenses - $1,000,000 
</div>
```